# ASP.NET 5 SecretManager Production Values for Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, secret-manager

I'm just using the [SecretManager](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-Secret-Configuration) in ASP.NET 5 and don't quite understand how I'm meant to set these values for production / staging environments on Azure website.

Is there a user interface somewhere, do I just add them as AppSettings in the Azure portal, or do I need to use the Kudu Debug Console to set them?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the code that configures UserSecrets -

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

It simply adds the UserSecrets to the collection of environment variables whenever the environment is development.

So yes you need to add those secrets as standard App Settings when you deploy to Azure.

Comment: And note that all Azure Portal App Settings become environment variables. So you should never need to store secrets as files when deploying to Azure We Apps.